# pandas - combine strings of row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    id        text
    1         DM,HTN,Enlarged prostate
    2         hypertensive and on regular treatment
    2         LBP
    3         DM,HTN,Enlarged prostate
```

I want to combine the text of same id like this:

```
   id        text
   1         DM,HTN,Enlarged prostate
   2         hypertensive and on regular treatment LBP
   3         DM,HTN,Enlarged prostate
```

the texts of id 2 are combined. 
how can i acchieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) function `join`. Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("id")['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
print (grouped_df)
   id                                       text
0   1                   DM,HTN,Enlarged prostate
1   2  hypertensive and on regular treatment LBP
2   3                   DM,HTN,Enlarged prostate
```

Comment: Thanks for the details! Checking on the functions

Comment: It worked perfectly. might be even better than the other answer because I got a dataframe instead of series with this code. Saved me some work, appreciate it.

Comment: ah sorry, first time posting a question

Answer (score 3):

You can use group by function to do this

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("id").apply(lambda x: "%s" % ' '.join(x['text']))
```